# Conemu doesn't work with wsl since windows update

Tags: conemu, cmder

Since I have updated windows, my conemu terminal is giving me the following error each time a session is created:

```
wslbridge error: failed to start backend process
note: backend error output: -v: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
-v: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=0.
Press Enter or Esc to close console...
```

Has anyone an idea to bring conemu to a wsl terminal? Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/1930

Answer (score 42):

A similar error is caused by upgrading WSL from v1 to v2.

If you read through the discussion on this [github issue for ConEmu](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/1930) you'll find a variety of instructions that can be distilled into:

Change the command for the task {Bash::bash} to the following:

```
wsl.exe
```

Comment: Wow. That answer was to the point. The only uncertainty left is all the `ConEmuBaseDirShort` stuff in the original task.

Comment: Have you tried running wsl without it? It is no longer necessary for myself. Read through the GitHub ref as there are many different user scenarios, including using `-w` for setting starting folder, `--bash` for loading a .bashrc file.

Answer (score 17):

A [GitHub user posted this workaround](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/1930#issuecomment-640120326) which worked for me:

> I've fixed the issue by doing this:
>
> 1. Download latest `cygwin1-20200531.dll.xz` from https://cygwin.com/snapshots/ and unpack the file as `cygwin1.dll` into `ConEmu\wsl\` (replacing the original file there)
> 2. Download @Biswa96's `wslbridge2` from https://github.com/Biswa96/wslbridge2/releases and unpack to the same directory
> 3. Replacing `{WSL::bash}` task's Command with:
>
> ```
> set "PATH=%ConEmuBaseDirShort%\wsl;%PATH%" & %ConEmuBaseDirShort%\conemu-cyg-64.exe %ConEmuBaseDirShort%\wsl\wslbridge2.exe -cur_console:pm:/mnt -eConEmuBuild -eConEmuPID -eConEmuServerPID -l
> ```
>
> I can now access my Ubuntu under W10 just like before the W10 upgrade. Backscroll and arrows in VIM work as expected.

The key part of step 3 is to replace `conemu-cyg-64.exe --wsl` with `conemu-cyg-64.exe %ConEmuBaseDirShort%\wsl\wslbridge2.exe`.

Longer term, it looks like the author of ConEmu is working on switching to the new [Windows PTY API](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-introducing-the-windows-pseudo-console-conpty/), which will eliminate the need for the wslbridge hack (and many others) entirely.

Comment: Looks like you don't need step 1 now -- there's a `cygwin1.dll` in the archive that comes down with step 2.
Regardless, this work-around is still working, so thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with last update windows

(Feature update to Windows 10, version 2004 - Successfully installed on ‎9/‎1/‎2020)

the error does not seem to be related to the version of WSL from 1 to 2:

```
   $ wsl -l -v
    
     NAME            STATE           VERSION
    
    Ubuntu-20.04    Running         1
```

Nevertheless, this workaround worked for me as well, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Exactly this goes through upgrading WSL from v1 to v2.

You have to open cmder and in the startup command or Task enter {wsl.exe} and ready

cmder is working again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the new command for WSL2 is much simpler, but just running `wsl` does not cause `.profile` to be read because launching this way does not request login shell, and it launches as `root`.

A better command is to specify the user id and to invoke the shell of your choice (`bash` is most common) with the appropriate option. For `bash` a login shell is desirable so `.profile`, `.bashrc` and `.bash_aliases` get sourced, if present. The `-l` (lower case `L`) does that:

```
wsl -U yourUserName bash -l
```